# Rails 4: render string field as JSON / hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails model in which one of the text fields contains a JSON string. While rendering it in views with JSON format (such as through index or show) I want to convert the string to a JSON hash. How can I do this with jbuilder or otherwise?

In general, how to apply a transform on a field by calling some function, before rendering it via jbuilder.

Of course, the naive solution is to build the JSON manually and use `render json: my_json_here` but I am looking for a better way.

Comment: You can pass a serialized string of json with no problems :) E.g. `render json: '{"a":"b"}'` should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well a JSON is a string already... Maybe you want to convert it back to an object...

This will transform you string into a hash or array object.

`JSON.parse(string)`

If you want to make the other way around, transform you hash or array into a JSON string:

`{ foo: 'bar' }.to_json # "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"`

EDIT: As you are looking for something more advanced, I recommend using the gem ActiveModelSerializer, where you create serializer objects that can be used to render ActiveModel data into any format, like JSON.

Comment: I know how to parse JSON. But how would I include that in the output of the API without manually generating the whole JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `"serialization"` to do this where all of the conversion from JSON object to string and back is handled by ruby.
[apidock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class)